# What is the fastest way to conditionally change the values of a dataframe in every index and column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to reduce by a constant number each element of a dataframe verifying a condition including their own value without using a loop?

For instance, each cells < 2 sees its value reducing by 1.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am sure there are some ways, however, would you like show us some sample data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to do this masking.
Here is an inefficient loop using your example

```
 #Example using loop
 for val in df['column']:
      if(val<2):
           val = val - 1
```

The following code gives the same result, but it will generally be much faster because it does not use a loop.

```
 # Same effect using masks
 mask = (df['column'] < 2) #Find entries that are less than 2.
 df.loc[mask,'column'] = df.loc[mask,'column'] - 1 #Subtract 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the fastest, but you can use the .apply function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1,2,3], [2,2,2], [4,4,4]]), 
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

def conditional_add(x):
    if x > 2:
        return x + 2
    else:
        return x

df['x'] = df['x'].apply(conditional_add)
```

Will add 2 to the final row of column x.

Comment: `.apply` is considered slow. You should always prefer built-in vectorized operations on Pandas data-frames. A convenience function of "last resort"

Answer (score 0):

More like (data from Willie)

```
df-((df<2)*2)
Out[727]: 
    x  y  z
0  -1  2  3
1   2  2  2
2   4  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use the `np.where` method from the NumPy library.
The method uses the following logic:
`np.where(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)`

Example:

```
# import modules which are needed
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create exmaple dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,1,5,0.5,2,0.2]})

|  A  |
|-----|
|   3 |
|   1 |
|   5 |
| 0.5 |
|   2 |
| 0.2 |

# apply the np.where method with conditional statement
df['A'] = np.where(df.A < 2, df.A - 1, df.A)

|  A   |
|------|
|    3 |
|  0.0 |
|    5 |
| -0.5 |
|    2 |
| -0.8 |`
```